# Nuxt access component's method or data in hook fetch/asyncData

Tags: vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js, asyncdata

On my component i have follow script:

```html
<script>
 export default {
  data(){
   return {
    posts: [],
   }
  }
  methods: {
   async get_post(){
    return await this.$axios('post')
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

I want to access my data and my methods from fetch or asyncData hook without using the axios directly there, tried "this" on fetch but only data is accessible but not the methods, on asyncData i can't even access the two.

Comment: Why would you need to have a method inside of this kind of hook?

Answer (score 0):

according to the [doc: Data Fetching](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/)

### `asyncData`

you can only access the context in `asyncData()`(also, please remember the `asyncData()` is only avaiables in page components)

so you can code like

```html
<script>
 export default {
  asyncData({ $axios }){
    return $axios.post('/users')
  }
 }
</script>
```

### `fetch`

but you can access the data and methods in `fetch()`

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    posts: []
  }),
  async fetch() {
    this.posts = await this.$http.$get('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/posts')
  },
  fetchOnServer: false,
  // multiple components can return the same `fetchKey` and Nuxt will track them both separately
  fetchKey: 'site-sidebar',
  // alternatively, for more control, a function can be passed with access to the component instance
  // It will be called in `created` and must not depend on fetched data
  fetchKey(getCounter) {
    // getCounter is a method that can be called to get the next number in a sequence
    // as part of generating a unique fetchKey.
    return this.someOtherData + getCounter('sidebar')
  }
}
```

Comment: so i can access data if i don't put paramater on fetch, but the problem is i can't access error function anymore